# Materialize Tabs aren't working in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, materialize

I've been working on a project in Laravel, I used Materialize as a front-end framework !
My problem is in `Materialize.js` file and `jQuery-3.3.1.min.js`, both aren't working, I added `console.log()` function to be sure and the code isn't even working on both ...

This is my `app.blade.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'E-Commerce Test') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/materialize.js') }}" defer>
        console.log("I am 1");  
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}" defer>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tabs').tabs();
        console.log("I am 2");
  });
    </script>
    <script>
        console.log("I am 3");
    </script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: Indie Flower, cursive;
            src: url('{{ public_path('/public/fonts/IndieFlower.ttf') }}');
        }
    </style>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/materialize.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/costume.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body>
    @include('inc.navbar')
    <div id="app">

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    @include('inc.footer')

    <script src="{{ asset('js/materialize.js') }}" defer>
        console.log("I am 1");  
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}" defer>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tabs').tabs();
        console.log("I am 2");
  });
      </script>

    <script>
        console.log("I am 4");
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            options ={};
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
            var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
  });
    </script>

    <script>
        console.log("I am 5");
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

And here it is my **Tabs code**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="tab"><a href="#winter">Winter</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#summer">Summer</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#sports">Sports</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#cos">Costumized</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#cla">Classic</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#tra">Traditional</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12" id="winter">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae quo porro, doloribus nulla,
            pariatur beatae consequatur eaque sequi quaerat ipsam,
            enim atque assumenda quis quisquam.
            Pariatur ullam cum sint inventore!
        </div>
        <div class="col s12" id="summer">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae quo porro, doloribus nulla,
            pariatur beatae consequatur eaque sequi quaerat ipsam,
            enim atque assumenda quis quisquam.
            Pariatur ullam cum sint inventore!
        </div>
        <div class="col s12" id="sports">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae quo porro, doloribus nulla,
            pariatur beatae consequatur eaque sequi quaerat ipsam,
            enim atque assumenda quis quisquam.
            Pariatur ullam cum sint inventore!
        </div>
        <div class="col s12" id="cos">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae quo porro, doloribus nulla,
            pariatur beatae consequatur eaque sequi quaerat ipsam,
            enim atque assumenda quis quisquam.
            Pariatur ullam cum sint inventore!
        </div>
        <div class="col s12" id="cla">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae quo porro, doloribus nulla,
            pariatur beatae consequatur eaque sequi quaerat ipsam,
            enim atque assumenda quis quisquam.
            Pariatur ullam cum sint inventore!
        </div>
        <div class="col s12" id="tra">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae quo porro, doloribus nulla,
            pariatur beatae consequatur eaque sequi quaerat ipsam,
            enim atque assumenda quis quisquam.
            Pariatur ullam cum sint inventore!
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the console of Google Chrome i got "I am 3" , "I am 4" and "I am 5"
I tried to replace the script tags in the end of the file but no use :( 
I also used the Materialize **Dropdown** using JS and worked fine... Any idea guys ?

And Thanks guys in advance

Comment: Wouldn't you put the js tags near the footer instead of the header. I think you mentioned that, but still do that again. Then load jquery before your materialize js. After that look at your console log what It's saying

Comment: Still the same :/ ! nothing changed !!!

Comment: Load jquery before your material javascript

Comment: Try to use some standards, load js file at the bottom of your file. Load jquery at the top. Remove jquery defer. Remove codes in script src! If you want print anything in console open new script tags

Comment: Thanks guys for the help... I made the Tabs work but using the JavaScript not the jQuery... Although it would be amazing if the answer is given !

Comment: Answer was given you just not pay attention, i told you to open new scripts for your code and not to use codes in script src. Have fun.

Comment: Thank you for that ! I really appreciate it